# NestJS API cookies arent working on Heroku

Tags: express, heroku, cookies, nestjs

My NEST api works on localhost but cookies are not working on heroku.

Here is my config

```
  app.enableCors({ origin: process.env.FRONT_END_URL, credentials: true }); // FE_URL == http://localhost:3000 (a react app)
  app.set('trust proxy', 1); // I've seen people using express using this, but isn't working here
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.connection.proxySecure = true; // If i don't do this, it'll throw an error if i'm using secure == true and sameSite == 'none'
    next();
  });

  app.use(
    sessions({
      cookieName: 'FEATSession',
      secret: 'ThisIsMyTopSecretWord',
      duration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5,

      cookie: {
        path: '/', // Tried '/' and not setting this prop too
        // domain: 'feat-be.herokuapp.com', // I tried using and not using it too
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true, // Tried true and false too
      },
    }),
  );
```

Everything else is working fine, only cookies doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved myself a very similar problem today, try different syntax of setting cookie:
[SameSite property invalid Cookies HTTPONLY MERN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67941712/samesite-property-invalid-cookies-httponly-mern?noredirect=1#comment120088261_67941712)