# SameSite property invalid Cookies HTTPONLY MERN

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, backend, httponly

Same site property = none doesn't get applied, furthermore, it's telling me that property is invalid! I'm bewildered because no answers on SO helping! I'm building MERN app and need to store JWT token in HTTP only cookie. Everything was fine, but when deploying to Heroku (front and back on diff URLs) I can't keep cookie on frontend, because the browser is not accepting it, because it has same site lax property set by default. I try adding that property, here's it:
My express code

```js
res.cookie("nToken", token, {
        maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000000000,
        httpOnly: true,
        path: "/",
        sameSite: "none",
        secure:true,
        expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86409000).toUTCString(),
      });
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <here's my app link>
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Set-Cookie
Set-Cookie: HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: nToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYwYzM5ODg1ODIzMzlhMDAxNWMyMTcwMSIsImVtYWlsIjoiZW1haWxAbWFpbC5tZSIsImlhdCI6MTYyMzQzMTMwMSwiZXhwIjoxNjU0OTg4MjI3fQ.2P01XOOfEcDJYAuVc5Yzui60eG7IoIpFLRwO_AWix3g; Max-Age=7200000000; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 09 Aug 2249 01:08:21 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 54
Etag: W/"36-aZJNemOi1ZLLvYvfnmd2IxO+/h4"
Date: Fri, 11 Jun 2021 17:08:21 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

When I add that missing attribute, I get error that that object property is invalid! Or something like that... I'll be happy with any help! Has someone experienced it before? I tried setting it to false/None, "None", "none" - no difference! Even more errors!
server.js main backend file:

```js
const { shouldSendSameSiteNone } = require('should-send-same-site-none');

app.use(cookieParser());


app.use(shouldSendSameSiteNone);


const corsOptions = {
  origin: "here comes my link of frontend",
  credentials: true, //access-control-allow-credentials:true
  methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Set-Cookie');
  res.header("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None");
  // res.header(
  //   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  //   "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  // );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "here comes my link of frontend");

  next();
});
```

( I've removed some pieces of code, so it's more readable )

Frontend code calling it:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector("#signUp").addEventListener("click", async () => {
      const email = document.querySelector("#emailInput");
      const password = document.querySelector("#passInput");
      const res = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: vars.BACKENDURL + "/usercreate",
        withCredentials: true,
        data: { user: { email: email.value, password: password.value } },
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

[image: now it gives me]

Comment: please help rockstars, I'm stuck 'n' I'm feeling like I really need your help! :)

Comment: ```//app configuration
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000", /* whatever url with port number */
    credentials: true
}));```

Comment: Hello, Muhammad, do you mean to remove these:  methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
  optionSuccessStatus: 200, ? from options object passed to cors

Comment: Give it a try, it worked for me, remove all the configuration for cors and apply what I have given, and check it works or not

Comment: It's now giving me error option sameSite is invalid again :(. What was your res.cookie configuration when it worked for you? Can you please share it?

Comment: I've added an image what happens when I remove that samesite flag.. :( But thanks anyways for your help!

Comment: You should not be adding `Set-Cookie` to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. That header tells the browser what headers are accessible via JavaScript, and `Set-Cookie` should not be accessible via JavaScript.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, Thank you, I just gone insane, and am trying at least something that can help! I'm currently trying out one more way to solve it, and will share if it works!

Comment: GUYS I've solved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED! just replace syntax mentioned in my A post with such syntax:

```js
res.header("Set-Cookie", "nToken=" + token + ";Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None;Expires=31556926");
```